# SQL SELECT WHERE NOT IN from same table query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problem with the following SQL query and MySQL

```
SELECT
  id, cpid, label, cpdatetime
FROM
  mytable AS a
WHERE
  id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      mytable AS b
    WHERE
      a.label = b.label
    AND
      a.cpdatetime > b.cpdatetime
  )
AND
  label LIKE 'CB%'
AND
  cpid LIKE :cpid
GROUP BY label
ORDER BY cpdatetime ASC
```

the table looks like this

```
1 | 170.1 | CB55 | 2013-01-01 00:00:01
2 | 135.5 | CB55 | 2013-01-01 00:00:02
3 | 135.6 | CB59 | 2013-01-01 00:00:03
4 | 135.5 | CM43 | 2013-01-01 00:00:04
5 | 135.5 | CB46 | 2013-01-01 00:00:05
6 | 135.7 | CB46 | 2013-01-01 00:00:06
7 | 170.2 | CB46 | 2013-01-01 00:00:07
```

I would like my query to return

```
3 | 135.6 | CB59
5 | 135.5 | CB46
```

**Edit**

labels are dogs/cats and cpids are temporary family keeping the dogs/cats.

Dogs/cats move from family to family.

I need to find dogs/cats who were in :userinput family but only if they were not in another family previously

I can't alter the database and just have to work with the data as they are and I'm not the one who wrote the application/database schema.

Comment: Don't apologise - this is a well written question compared to others where you have prise information out using thumbscrews.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain why it should not return row 1? Is `:cpid = '13%'` perhaps?

Comment: @Dave no errors query just return empty

Comment: @lc. row 1 should not be returned because `cpid != '135%' AND a.cpdatetime > b.cpdatetime`

Comment: Strange the query should return empty, it [works on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1657f/2) (aside from also returning row 2)

Comment: It returns an extra row, but it really isn't quite working properly - it's doing a group by to reduce the rows; the id in ( ) clause isn't really doing anything, unless you have rows with identical ids [it won't do anything for the current query].  I find it odd that MySQL lets you select things that aren't in your group by or aggregate function...

Comment: the fiddle isn't really working, I don't want row 1, maybe my problem (returning no results) has to do with PHP, PDO or MySQL?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is in terms of results, but your code isn't right in any event.  Take a look at my answer, should solve your problem - if it doesn't work on your platform, perhaps your columns aren't defined the sam as the fiddle, or perhaps your :cpid variable isn't behaving.

Comment: @Jack sorry, edited the question labels are dogs/cats... it's late, thank you for the help

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` with numbers. It's not efficient and you may get erroneous results. For example, with `a.cpid LIKE '135%'`, a `1357.16` value will still pass the condition. Use: `a.cpid >= 135.0 AND a.cpid < 136.0`

Comment: @Υπερκύβος thanks for the tip, it's nice to learn, in my case though `cpid` is `VARCHAR(50)` and some fields look like `65.2.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to avoid correlated sub queries by using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.cpid, a.label, a.cpdatetime
FROM mytable AS a
LEFT JOIN mytable AS b ON a.label = b.label AND a.cpdatetime > b.cpdatetime
WHERE a.label LIKE 'CB%' AND a.cpid LIKE :cpid
  AND b.label IS NULL
GROUP BY a.label
ORDER BY a.cpdatetime ASC
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccccf/20)

If the join condition fails, the fields of the second table alias `b` will be set to `NULL`.

Alternatively, use a non-correlated sub query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.cpid, a.label, a.cpdatetime
FROM mytable AS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT label, MIN(cpdatetime) AS cpdatetime
  FROM mytable
  WHERE label LIKE 'CB%'
  GROUP BY label
) AS b ON a.label = b.label AND a.cpdatetime = b.cpdatetime
WHERE a.cpid LIKE '135%'
ORDER BY a.cpdatetime
```

First, you find the minimum `cpdatetime` for each label and then join that with the first table where you add the additional `cpid` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really what you want to do - select the IDs that are the earliest IDs for each label, then select out of those the records with a 135 cpid and a CB label.

```
SELECT
  A.id, cpid, A.label, cpdatetime
FROM
  mytable AS a inner join
 (select id, label from mytable
  group by label
  having min(cpdatetime)) as b
on A.label=B.label and A.id=B.id
WHERE
  A.label LIKE 'CB%'
AND
  cpid LIKE '135%'
GROUP BY A.label
ORDER BY cpdatetime ASC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccccf/16

Comment: Wouldn't `having min(cpdatetime)` always yield true?

Comment: both your solution and jack's work but I'm not sure which one I should mark as accepted. I understand jack's answer really easily compared to yours @joe so I'm not really sure, still trying to read on some more inputs and digging in MySQL documentation

Comment: Hm, I suppose it would, wouldn't it.  MySQL is just letting me cheat with the group by and returning the lowest numbered row, isn't it, rather than meaningfully evaluating it... sigh

Comment: @Joe Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccccf/25) that proves it would give the wrong results by simply switching two rows in order.